# Как сделать сочетание клавиш

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pygame

Как сделать сочетание клавиш левый LCTRL + BACKSPACE в pygame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [pygame.event.get()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) для отлова события нажатия кнопки `pygame.KEYDOWN`, определения нажатой кнопки через сравнение с `event.key` и [pygame.key.get_mods()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_mods), чтобы узнать какая клавиша модифицирования нажата

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6cb401cb54e7d8749845e2b6320b635ee74cccab/pygame__examples/on_press_lctrl+backspace.py)

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_LCTRL:
                print("pressed: LCTRL + BACKSPACE")

pygame.quit()
```

---

Второй вариант через [pygame.key.get_pressed](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed).

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f2a0990d0b7cb876831f9da8c64341f4b223a6e/pygame__examples/on_press_lctrl+backspace__key_get_pressed.py#L26)

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 200))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            elif keys[pygame.K_BACKSPACE] and keys[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
                print("pressed: LCTRL + BACKSPACE")

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: И снова спасибки (o･ω･o)

Comment: @Kity2891, пожалуйста :)

Comment: У меня первый вариант не работает.
Я делаю ввод текста в игру.
Ой я кажется забыла модуль

Comment: Нет все равно не работает первый вариант, а вот второй думаю как красиво упаковать на место

Comment: Хватит кодить спать ложитесь

Comment: Спят только слабаки, хехе

Comment: @Kity2891, скорее всего что-то не так делаете, оба варианта рабочие. Если не получается, то создайте вопрос с проблемным кодом :)

Comment: Мне и второго варианта хватит, а то беда с башкой будет, просто я изучила основы на метаните и пошла кодить и есть проблемы с модулем...
Я нашла только коротенькую шпаргалку про 
него       ...............(｡•́︿•̀｡)